# Challenging to determine if Cache for data has been changed in ASP.Net since a long operation began

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I am inserting a List into data cache in ASP.Net as shown in sample code below. I am using C# as the programming language.

I am not able to find a solution to following problem:

1. A long database operation which could last from .1 s to 20 s is started.
2. **At the end of this operation, I need to determine if the Cache by the name of 'dSummary' has been re-inserted or refreshed from database since the long operation began (i.e. while the operation was in progress).**

The code I use to insert cache item is as below:

```
      List<Doc> ds = GetDocSummary();
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("dSummary", ds, null, 
           DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

**UPDATE 1:**

After getting so many replies, I think a possible foolproof approach would be to store a guid string along with the List object in Cache. Then I could simply compare the guid string property of the object stored in Cache before and after the long operation. If they are the same then Cache["dSummary"] has not been re-inserted, else it has been re-inserted.
So I would need  to use the following extended class of 'Doc' class.

```
public class DocX : Doc
 { 
          public UniQueIdentifier { get;set; }
          public DocX ( Doc doc, string unqiueIdentifier)
             {
                  this.Doc = doc;
                  this.UniqueIdentifier = unqiueIdentifier;

            }
 }
```

I would then insert into cache using following code:

```
       List<Doc> ds = GetDocSummary();
       System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("dSummary",new DocX( ds,  
                new Guid.Newguid().ToString() ), null, 
           DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting the operation `GetDocSummary()` you could get the current value from the cache and store that value (or a Hash from this value, if memory might be an issue) in a local variable.
After the operation is finished, before adding the data to the cache, compare the local variable with the current cached value.

Adding some sample, based on the comments, using a `Tuple`:

```
var cacheEntry = new Tuple<List<Doc>, DateTime>(ds, DateTime.Now);
```

After executing `GetDocSummary()`, get your entry from the cache and see if the date falls between starting and ending this operation.

Comment: That could be a possible option except that we would end up comparing two List<Doc> in this case. 'Doc' is also a custom object.

Comment: In what way would that be a problem? Are you expecting performance problems? By means of functionality, I personally think this should work.

Comment: I would have to check whether each property of Doc object for each List element is equal. That would be quite a bit of code, unless there is some short-cut that I am missing.

Comment: Also, even if the objects before and after are same, it does not rule out whether a re-insert of cache item happened.  I want to know if a re-insert of that cache item happened.

Comment: Could you make your cached object a tuple then? You can save the change date along with the list in the same cache entry.

Comment: So would I use this code to retrieve it: var t =  Cache["dSummary"]? I think we would just get an object from Cache["DSummary"].

Comment: Would the object in cache be cast to Tuple<List<Doc>, DateTime> when retrieving it from Cache?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct cast. (Hope you already tried by now...)

Answer (score 2):

I would just add another Cache property at the time that you add or update dSummary that contains the timestamp that you modified it.

You can record the original value at the start of the long-running operation and compare it to the current value in the cache at the end; if the values are different, the data was updated.

Comment: Cache is unpredictable because ASP.Net could remove cache items whenever it feels it needs more memory. So I am looking for a more foolproof solution.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand the question then. You say that you need to determine if the cache has been inserted or updated, but then you say that you don't want to rely on the cache. Since you are controlling the access to the cache, you should have control over determining if it is not there and, if not add it (thus updating the timestamp). We use cache extensively and we always check for the existence of the cached item before accessing it; if it isn't there, we reload it.

Comment: May be I missed adding some clarity to my question. I needed to know whether the cache item was re-inserted since the long operation began.

Comment: This solution will work. If you need it to be more foolproof then insert a Pair object in the cache with the list and the datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are two or more threads that want to obtain docs summary, I guess you don't want all of them to compute the summary (as you said it is a long running operation that is compute intensive). In such case I go with following solution:

```
//declare lock object for implementing critical section
private static object docSummaryLock = new object();

//this is the body of GetDocSummary method
List<Doc> ds = (List<Doc>) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("dSummary");
if (ds != null) return ds;
//summary not found in cache, computing the doc summary occurs in critical section
lock (docSummaryLock)
{
    //there is possibility that another thread waited for obtaining the lock and the summary may be already in cache
    ds = (List<Doc>) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("dSummary");
    if (ds != null) return ds;

    //compute the summary
    ds = GetDocSummary();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("dSummary", summaries, null, 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: I think Cache access is thread-safe and so doesn't need thread synchronization as you have mentioned. Also, my question is not on how to access Cache but something else.

Comment: This code is not about synchronizing access to cache, it is about not computing it twice. What do you really want to check?

Comment: Before the operation there is a Cache["dSummary"]. Then, after the operation has ended, I need to know if Cache["dSummary"] was re-inserted while the long operation was in progress.

Comment: So you have the summary in cache and you still compute it? What is more you want to compute it on different threads simultaneously? Why don't you allow just one thread to compute at a time?

Comment: The app runs in a multi-user environment. If the long operation lasts for 20 seconds ( this operation does NOT populate Cache but it updates some tables in database), then its quite possible that the cache item Cache['dSummary'] was removed from Cache and re-inserted, while the long operation was in progress.

Comment: @Sunil: your question is really unclear. Do you want to check if value in cache is the same before and after the operation? Or do you want to check if value in cache was replaced (and you don't care if summary changed, but you're only interested if cache item expired)? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to know if the cache item was re-inserted since the operation began. This is mentioned in my bullet#2 that is in bold.

Comment: So, my question is like the second question you have in your last comment.

Comment: @Sunil: if it is safe to assume that you're not interested in scenario that someone adds to cache exactly the same object then Jacco's answer should be okay. You may use Object.ReferenceEquals(dsBefore, dsAfter) to be sure if it is exactly the same object (the same identity).

Comment: But Object.ReferenceEquals could return a true even when the cache was re-inserted during the operation? Like if the cache expired and was re-populated by another user while long operation was in progress, but the values in cache are still the same for List<doc> object. Right?

Comment: Only if someone inserted exactly same List<Doc> object. E.g. var a = new List<Doc>(); var b = new List<Doc>(); are different in terms of Object.ReferenceEquals.

Comment: What I need to know is if a re-insert has happened even though the same object got re-inserted. So  Object.ReferenceEquals(dsBefore, dsAfter) will not help in determining this.

Comment: It appears then a re-insert will always mean Object.ReferenceEquals returns a false. right? I guess this approach can get very tricky.